# Adding a Hook to manipulate JUnit Output

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working in a Java project with the following scenario:

- We have JUnit tests which are converted into a nice HTML report using maven-surefire-report plugin.
- Our test department maintains detailed descriptions of each test in a Jira kanban board.

Unfortunately, our test guys aren't software developers and have problems understanding exceptions, stack traces, package names, etc. To help them a little bit, I want to add a link to the Jira board in case a test fails.

Example: *Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element ... See https://our.jira.com/ABC-123 for test documentation details*

So basically, what I want to achieve is: Filtering each JUnit Assert/Uncaught exception message and add a link to the corresponding Jira page. My first idea is:

- Implementing a wrapper `Assert` class which inherits from JUnits `Assert` and extends error messages with the previously described HTML links
- Using a `try{...} catch(Exception e){modify exception msg here}` at top level in my `@Test` methods the get and modify exception messages with the previously described HTML links.

My question is: Is this the way to go? Or are the better ways to achieve this? Has anybody had the same problem?

Kind regards,

Christian